# How to perform significance tests on distributions with unclear sample size?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance

I have a problem that seems like it should be very simple, but I've come up dry searching for answers (which probably indicates some basic conceptual failure on my part).

Basically, I have two sets of measurements that I need to multiply in order to get a third value, and I want to compare this value between two populations. Each set of measurements obviously has an associated error, and I understand how to propagate the error using the standard formulae. This gives me the derived value and its error term. However, in order to perform a t-test I'd also need the sample size, and I don't know what that would mean for this derived value (particularly because the two original sets of measurements had different sample sizes).

**EDIT** *I think that the BMI framing is a bad example, so please ignore. My actual problem is below.*

My actual application is in cell biology, but in order to avoid getting down into the weeds with the details I have a toy example that I think captures the problem: imagine I want to determine whether body mass index (BMI, which is $\frac{weight}{height^2}$) is significantly different between men and women.

Unfortunately I don't have a dataset of BMIs from individual men and women, but I do have separate datasets of height (*n* = 100) and weight (*n* = 200) for both men and women (assume both datasets were sampled from identical populations). It seems I should be able to estimate the average BMI as

$\mu_{BMI} = \frac{\mu_{weight}}{\mu_{height}^2}$

and the error as

$\sigma_{BMI} = \lvert \mu_{BMI}\rvert
\sqrt 
  {\left(\frac
    {\sigma_{weight}}{\mu_{weight}}\right)^2+2
  {\left(\frac
    {\sigma_{height}}{\mu_{height}}\right)^2}
}$

But how would I run a t-test on these average BMIs? All the t-test formulae require a sample size *n* and I don't know what that would mean in this case since the BMI is calculated from two samples of different sizes. Or is a t-test the wrong test to use?

Thanks in advance, and apologies for the inevitable errors.

**EDIT**

I'm running two experiments: in one, I feed cells in a dish some isotope-labeled glucose, and do some mass spec analysis to determine what fraction of glucose enters the pentose phosphate pathway (*n* = 5 biological replicates); in the other, I measure the total amount of glucose consumed (*n* = 6). Multiplying those measurements (fraction of glucose entering PPP X amount of glucose consumed) gives me what I want (amount of glucose entering PPP).

If I want to then see whether (amount of glucose entering PPP) differs significantly between two strains of cells, how would I run the test? Unlike in the BMI example, where you can and should measure individual heights/weights, for technical reasons I have to make these measurements in separate experiments. So if I multiply a measured quantity with *n*=5 by another quantity with *n*=6, what's the sample size of the derived quantity? Or am I just thinking about it wrong, and there's another test I should be using?

Comment: I think you’re making a mistake by not considering the paired heights and weights. Imagine heights of 1, 2, 3, and 4, with corresponding weights of 5, 6, 9, and 9. I get an average BMI of $2.015625$. The average height is $2.5$, and the average weight is $7.25$, yet $7.25/2.5^2 = 1.16 \ne 2.015625$. (This is cell phone arithmetic, so do check it, but I think this will give an example of why you can’t just divide the average weight by the squared average height.)

Comment: That's an excellent point, and I suspect that my BMI example may have obscured more than it illuminated; it was simply the first simple example of a measure that's derived from two other measures that sprang to mind. I've edited the original question with my actual problem in hopes that it will be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Is the composite hypothesis really the primary interest?  For example if one cell line consumes 10 percent of 100 (hence 10) and the other line consumes 20 percent of 50 (also 10) then you null hypothesis would be true even though the routes are very different.  It may be the most interesting to start with 2 separate tests, one comparing the 2 lines on fraction entering and the other comparing on glucose consumed) and see if they differ on either measure.  These tests would fit into the more traditional t-test framework directly.

If you are really interested in comparing the products, then you may want to switch to a Bayesian analysis where you can estimate your parameters of interest, then just multiply them together and look at the posterior(s) and credibly/compatibility intervals for the difference (or ratio) of your 2 products (as well as looking at the individual means).

Comment: _Is the composite hypothesis really the primary interest?_

Unfortunately, yes, since the real thing that we care about is in fact the amount of "product" coming out of that metabolic pathway (specifically, NADPH production rate by the pentose phosphate pathway). There are some technically very challenging ways to try to measure that directly, but the more common way is to measure (1) glucose consumption flux and (2) the fraction of glucose going into the PPP, and then multiply.

Thanks for the suggestions, I'll take a look into that.